# node-postgres create database

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am using [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres), and at the beginning of my application I want to check whether the database exists or not. So my workflow idea is as following:

1. Check whether `myDb` is existing
2. If it is there, create the tables
3. If not, then create first the database, then tables

As you see it is a really easy process, however, the driver implementation requires to have a database name `postgres://username:password@host/database` to be connected, which means you need to connect to a database first.

So what I am doing now is to connect to `postgres` database at the beginning, making a query to create database, cathing the exception if it is already there, then closing my connection and connecting to the newly created database, then creating the tables. Here is the code:

```
var conStringPri = 'postgres://' + username + ':' + password + '@' + host + 
    '/postgres';
var conStringPost = 'postgres://' + username + ':' + password + '@' + host + 
    '/' + dbName;

pg.connect(conStringPri, function(err, client, done) { // connect to postgres db
    if (err)
        console.log('Error while connecting: ' + err); 
    client.query('CREATE DATABASE ' + dbName, function(err) { // create user's db
        if (err) 
            console.log('ignoring the error'); // ignore if the db is there
        client.end(); // close the connection

        // create a new connection to the new db
        pg.connect(conStringPost, function(err, clientOrg, done) {
            // create the table
            clientOrg.query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + tableName + ' ' +
                    '(...some sql...)';
        });
    });
});
```

As you see I am opening and closing the connection twice, and this way seems wrong to me. I'll be glad if you propose a better way, or maybe explain how did you accomplish this.

Comment: As far as I know there is no command to switch the database you are connected to (in psql there is `\c nameOfOtherDb` but that is a command in psql that create a new connection and closes the old one).

Comment: Another technique: you could just use a query to see if it exists from one connection (from an "administrative" connection): `select count(*) from pg_catalog.pg_database where datname = 'the_db_name_here';`, then create/open the second connection. If you're connecting to 2 databases, this doesn't seem like an issue.

Comment: fetching the available dbs and checking whether mine is there will create an if/else and this will break my synchronous callbacks. that's why i ended up creating the db and catch the exception

Comment: In the line that says `// ignore if the db is there`, you are ignoring all errors.  To just ignore the duplicate db error, you can do something like  `if (err && err.code === '42P04') { console.log('ignoring the error'); } else if (err) { throw  err; }`

Answer (score 20):

> As you see it is a really easy process, however, the driver
>   implementation requires to have a database name
>   postgres://username:password@host/database to be connected, which
>   means you need to connect to a database first.

It's not because of the driver implementation, it's PostgreSQL itself. It's the same with any other language or driver.

A client needs to be connected to a database in order to do anything, including a `CREATE DATABASE`. Besides the `postgres` database, `template1` is often used for this purpose too.

Then, since you must connect to the freshly created database to create objects inside it, there's no way to avoid opening another connection.

In short, what you're doing can't be simplified, it's already optimal.

Answer (score 17):

I've just written a module for that: https://github.com/olalonde/pgtools

```
var pgtools = require('pgtools');
pgtools.createdb({
  user: 'postgres',
  password: 'some pass',
  port: 5432,
  host: 'localhost'
}, 'test-db', function (err, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(-1);
  }
  console.log(res);
});
```

Hopefully it can make your code a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 8):

This is a bit old but I just want to share how I handled this kind of setup.

You need to call the third param from the callback which is the `done` from `pg.connect(conn, (err, client, done) => {})`. This will release the connection and bring back to pool.

```
 async.series([
   done => {
     pg.connect(connPrimary, (err, client, releaseConn) => {
      if (err) return done(err)

      client.query(`CREATE DATABASE ${conf.database}`, (err) => {
        if (err && !~err.message.indexOf('already exists')) {
          return done(err)
        }

        client.end()
        releaseConn()
        done()
      })
    })
  },
  done => {
    let connSecondary = `postgres://${conf.user}:${conf.password}@${conf.host}:${conf.port}/${conf.database}`

    pg.connect(connSecondary, (err, client, releaseConn) => {
      if (err) return done(err)

      let createTableQuery = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table(_id bigint primary key, co2_field varchar(40) NOT NULL, temp_field int NOT NULL, quality_field decimal NOT NULL, reading_time_field timestamp NULL)`

      client.query(createTableQuery, err => {
        if (err) return done(err)

        releaseConn()
        done()
      })
    })    
  }
], err => {
  should.ifError(err)
  doneInit()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script I use which is essentially just executing shell commands with execa:

```
import execa from 'execa';

class DatabaseService {
  public async setupDatabase() {
    const logCmd = (cmd: execa.ExecaChildProcess) => {
      cmd.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        this.logger.log(data.toString());
      });

      cmd.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        this.logger.error(data.toString());
      });
    };

    const createUser = () => {
      return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        const cmd = execa('createuser', [Config.databaseUser, '--superuser']);

        logCmd(cmd);

        let userExists = false;

        cmd.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
          if (
            data
              .toString()
              .includes(`role "${Config.databaseUser}" already exists`)
          ) {
            userExists = true;
          }
        });

        cmd.on('exit', (code) => {
          if (!userExists && code) {
            reject(new Error(`Failed to create user for database: ${code}`));
          } else {
            resolve();
          }
        });
      });
    };

    const createDatabase = () => {
      return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        const cmd = execa('createdb', [Config.databaseName]);

        logCmd(cmd);

        let databaseExists = false;

        cmd.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
          if (
            data
              .toString()
              .includes(`database "${Config.databaseName}" already exists`)
          ) {
            databaseExists = true;
          }
        });

        cmd.on('exit', (code) => {
          if (!databaseExists && code) {
            reject(new Error(`Failed to create database: ${code}`));
          } else {
            resolve();
          }
        });
      });
    };

    await createUser();
    await createDatabase();
  }
}
```

As you can see, the script detects if the user or database already exists and will ignore errors in those events, because the intended state of Postgres will have been met, and thats all I care about when I run it.

Answer (score -2):

Install

```
npm install --save -g pgtools
```

CLI Example

```
createdbjs my_awesome_db --user=admin --password=admin
```

Comment: Please review the answer to help the OP.