# Is there a way to create the database if it doesn`t exist with sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize connection.

Then I create every table I need if they don't already exist. However, before I do that, I want to create the schema itself if it doesn`t exist, so I can run this script anywhere that has mysql installed and not worry. Is there a way to do so with sequelize? Or with any other tool if not.

Comment: try a combination of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52915491/62282) and [sync](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-method-sync)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31294562/sequelize-create-database/52915491#52915491) answer as proposed by [Samuel G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62282/samuel-g):

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

await mysql.createConnection({
    user     : user,
    password : pwd
}).then((connection: Sequelize) => {
    connection.query(`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${name};`);
});
```

Comment: This works for non-sequelize sessions too, thanks for the answer.